# How to save Dictionary object to database in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

So, I am sending a dictionary object to my view from the controller.

```
    // GET: QuestionResponses/Create
    public ActionResult Create(int questionnaireUID)
    {
        var questions = from q in db.QUESTIONS
                        where q.QuestionnaireUID == questionnaireUID
                        select q;


        ViewBag.NextQuestion = from q in db.QUESTIONS
                               where q.QuestionnaireUID == questionnaireUID
                               select new SelectListItem
                               {
                                   Selected = (q.QuestionnaireUID == questionnaireUID),
                                   Text = q.Question1,
                                   Value = q.QuestionUID.ToString()
                               };

        Dictionary<QUESTION, QUESTION_RESPONSES> dict = new Dictionary<QUESTION, QUESTION_RESPONSES>();

        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            dict.Add(question, new QUESTION_RESPONSES { QuestionUID = question.QuestionUID, Response = "", NextQuestion = "" });
        }

        return View(dict);
    }
```

The reasoning behind this is that I need to view data from one model and need to add/edit data from another model. I tried using Tuples and was not able to get it to work (if you could tell me how to do this with Tuples, that would be helpful too).

This is what the view does with this Dictionary object.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <h2> Reponses </h2>
                <p> For each question, enter in the appropriate response(s). All questions must have at least one response. <p>
                    <div id="editorRows">
                        <div class="rows_no_scroll">
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ToArray())
                            {

                                <!-- The question that responses are being added to. -->
                                Html.RenderPartial("QuestionRow", item.Key);

                                <!-- All questions pertaining to this questionnaire. -->
                                // <p>Please select the question which should be asked as a response to this question.</p>
                                @Html.DropDownList("NextQuestion", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddl_questions_" + count})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Value.NextQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                <!-- The next question link and responses being inputted by user. -->
                                Html.RenderPartial("ResponseEditorRow", item.Value);

                                // <p> Question @count </p>
                                count += 1;
                            }
                        </div> <!--/rows_no_scroll-->
                </div> <!-- /editorRows -->
            </div> <!-- /form-group -->
```

For completeness, here are what the partial views are doing.

QuestionRow:

```
    <div class="questionRow">

    <!-- Hide attribute(s) not being viewed/edited. -->
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionUID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionnaireUID)

    <!-- Show attribute(s) being viewed. -->
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Question1)

    <div class="addQuestion"><a href="" class="addItemResponse" name="addRow[]">Add Response</a></div>

</div>
```

ResponseEditorRow:

```
    <div class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("questions"))
    {
        <!-- Hide attribute(s) not being viewed/edited. -->
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ResponseUID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionUID)

        <br>

        <!-- Display attribute(s) being edited. -->
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Response, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @name = "question", @class = "question_input" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Response, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="deleteRow" value="Delete">
    }
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that when I get back to my controller to POST the data inserted by the user, my Dictionary is empty. I'm not sure if I am inserting the information correctly. I am changing the dictionary object toArray(), not sure if this is affecting anything...

Here is the HTTP POST create method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ResponseUID, QuestionUID, Response, NextQuestion")] Dictionary<QUESTION, QUESTION_RESPONSES> question_question_response)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            foreach (var item in question_question_response.ToArray())
            {
                db.QUESTION_RESPONSES.Add(item.Value);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Update to take user to Actions/Create page.
            }
        }

        ViewBag.NextQuestion = new SelectList(db.QUESTIONS, "QuestionUID", "Question1");
        return View(question_question_response);
    }
```

Open to any suggestions of different ways I could do this or on what may be wrong with what I am currently doing.

Comment: I think it will be better to make a ViewModel,

Comment: Nothing will bind because your generating controls with name attributes which have no relationship to your model. Use a view model with properties for `Question` and `Responses` and use `EditorTemplates` for the types.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 ViewModels:

```
public class QuestionAireViewModel {

public int QuestionAireId {get;set;}

public List<QuestionViewModel> Quesitons {get;set;}

}


public class QuestionViewModel{

public int QuestionId {get;set;}

public string Question {get;set;}

public string QuestionResponse {get;set;}

}
```

In your view pass this `QuestionAireViewModel`

Generate `QuestionAireViewModel` in your controller like this:

```
    public ActionResult GetQuestions(int id)
    {
    var questionAire = db.QuesitonAire.First(s => s.QuestionAireId == id)

    var questions = new List<QuestionViewModel>();

    foreach(var question in questionAire.Questions){

    questions.Add(new QuestionViewModel(){
    Quesiton = question.Question,
    });

    }


    var model = new QuestionAireViewModel(){
    QuestionAireId = questionAire.Id,
    Quesitons  = questions 
    };

return View(model);

    }
```

Then on POST Form method will be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveQuestions(QuestionAireViewModel model)
{

}
```